# Understanding a definition of continuity with a specific example

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm reviewing mathematical analysis from the book [Mathematical Analysis: A Concise Introduction by Bernd S. W. Schröder](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470107960).

In [section 3.4](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=jaE0dvv309YC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Bernd+Schroeder&redir_esc=y&hl=en#v=onepage&q=Bernd%20Schroeder&f=false) the author gives the following definition for continuous functions:

> Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R} $ be an interval of nonzero length from which at most finitely  many points have been removed and let $f : D \to \mathbb{R} $ be a function. Then $f$ is called *continuous at* $x$ iff
>
> 1. $f(x)$ is defined, that is, $x \in D$, and
> 2. $\lim_{z \to x}f(z)$ exists, and
> 3. $\lim_{z \to x}f(z)=f(x)$, and
> 4. If $x$ is an endpoint of $D$, use left or right limits in 2 and 3, as appropriate.
>
> $f$ is called *continuous* (on $D$)  iff $f$ is continuous at every $x \in D$.

He remarks:

> We could also define continuity for functions defined on sets for which every point 
>   of the domain is contained in an interval of  nonzero length. Exercise 3-32 shows that 
>   with the present definition this idea is a bit too simple to produce a sensible result.

Now, exercise 3-32 is the following:

> Let $U = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}[\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{10n}, \frac{1}{n}]=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}:(\exists n\in \mathbb{N}: x \in [\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{10n}, \frac{1}{n}])\}$ and let the function $f : [-1,0] \cup U \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in [-1,0]$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $x \in U$.
>
> 1. Prove that $f$ is continuous on every interval $I$ that is contained in its domain $D = [-1,0] \cup U$.
> 2. Prove that every point in $D$ is contained in an interval of nonzero length.
> 3. Explain why the function still should not be considered to be continuous on $D$.
> 4. Suggest a generalization of the definition of continuity that would allow domains such as $D$ and that would make $f$ discontinuous at $0$.

Since $(-0.01, 0.01) \subseteq D$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x) = 1 \neq 0 = \lim_{x \to 0-}f(x)$, I don't understand why the function $f$ is continuous at $0$ according to the above definition.

Much later in the book the author gives a more general definition of continuity on metric spaces which supposedly "resolves the problem" with the above definition and can be used to prove that the defined function indeed doesn't have a limit at $x = 0$ (exercise 16-29).

---

**EDIT:**

Following the comments, I'll prove that $(0,0.01) \subset U$ (and therefore $(-0.01, 0.01) \subseteq D$). Let $ x \in (0, 0.01)$. Choose $ n \in \mathbb{
N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n+1} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{n}$. Since $ x< 0.01$, it follows that $n \geq 100 > 9$. Therefore,
$$9 < n \iff 9n+9 < 10n \iff 10(n+1) -(n+1) <10n \iff \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{10n} < \frac{1}{n+1}$$
so
$$ \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{10n} < \frac{1}{n+1} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{n} $$
and thus $x \in U$. $\square$

Comment: "*Since $(-0.01,0.01)\subseteq D$*"... are you sure about that?

Comment: @JMoravitz Please see my comment to the answer below. I'm probably missing something trivial but why it is not true that $(-0.01, 0.01) \subset D$?

Comment: @JMoravitz Well, it seems the answer was deleted... My reasoning is that for $n > 9$, the intervals overlap so $(0,0.01) \subset U$ and therefore $(-0.01, 0.01) \subset D$.